# Adding vertical space below a <code> element in a table

Tags: html, css

I have some fixed-width content I would like to put in a table header cell
with a little bubble around it to distinguish from non-fixed-width text.

The example below looks great except the bubble bottom covers up the cell border.

[image]

I would like to fix by moving the text up by 1, can't seem to figure it out; in effect, I *think* I want the baseline of the `code.literal` text to be 1-2px higher than the normal `<th>` baseline.

Is there a way to do this?

```css
code.literal {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Consolas,Menlo,"Liberation Mono",Courier,monospace;
}

th, td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.small {
    font-size: 75%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Aluminum <code class="literal small">foo.bar.baz.quux</code></th>
    <th>Barium <code class="literal small">jabberwocky</code></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you add `position: relative; top: -1px;` to your `code.literal` rule it will jump up 1px

Comment: You could also add bottom padding to your cells `.table td, table th { padding-bottom: 1px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `display: inline-block;` to your `code.literal`, the table will contain the element as a block level item instead. Which I think is what you are going for here.

```css
code.literal {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Consolas,Menlo,"Liberation Mono",Courier,monospace;
    display: inline-block;
}

th, td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.small {
    font-size: 75%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Aluminum <code class="literal small">foo.bar.baz.quux</code></th>
    <th>Barium <code class="literal small">jabberwocky</code></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @JasonS This is probably the better way to go, though it will keep both text at the same baseline, and if you still _think_ you want the _code.literal_ higher, the `position: relative` I suggested will solve that.

Comment: @JasonS worth to note that the issue here is the use of padding that is not considered when the element is inline by default, adding inline-block will make this padding to be considered and the element will remain an inline level element (not a block level one)